# Making JQuery LightBox Plugin work with multiple galleries

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, lightbox

I'm trying to make this jquery plugin => http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/
work with multiple galleries on the same page.

The problem is, everytime I click on a picture from a certain gallery, I get all the pictures from all the galleries on the same page. Let's say i've got 2 galleries of 6 photos each. If I click on a pic from gallery 1, I will see the pics from gallery 2 as well.

I've tried something like this to make it work but no success:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
      $('div.gallery-6').each(function() {
        $(this).find('a.lightbox').lightBox();
      });
    });
</script>
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work!!!

What's the workaround for that?

Once again, what I'm trying to accomplish is to be able to view the pictures in their proper gallery. I don't want all the pics to be treated as one gallery.

Comment: put the HTML you're trying to match with the selectors as well (I think it's a selector problem)

Comment: also, `$( 'div.gallery-6 a.lightbox' ).lightBox( );` is the same thing as what you're doing with less code (pretty sure it's the exact same)

Comment: it's not... since i want the plugin to treat my galleries as 2 different galleries. Let's say one gallery contains a certain set of pics and the other one contains another set of pics. When you browse through the first gallery, you should not see the other ones.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With very few changes I made this work with multiple galleries on one page.

The JQuery

```
$(function() {
  $('#gallery1 a').lightBox();
  $('#gallery2 a').lightBox();
  ...
  $('#galleryN a').lightBox();   
});
```

The HTML

```
<div class="gallery" id="gallery1">
<div class="gallery" id="gallery2">
...
<div class="gallery" id="galleryN">
```

I changed the style from an id to a class.

Comment: I just tried this solution... It works perfectly thx. But why, in that case, my previous code didn't work? I mean, calling the lightbox function twice is the same as finding an element, in my case the gallery div and then on each gallery div find the "a" elements and calling the lightbox function... I wouldnt have to give the gallery an ID cause i call the each() method on the gallery div.

Comment: also 
`$('.gallery').each(function(i) {
   $('#gallery'+i).lightbox();
});
`

Answer (score 6):

This a patch for Ben's answer, for those who waht to use multiple galleries, or simply add the lightbox effect to an image, use it inside your `<head>...</head>` tag

Here's the code (Note: I changed the variable `$` for `jQuery`, it works better for me):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function() {
        var boxen = [];
        //find all links w/ rel="lightbox[gallery_name]" or just rel="lightbox" it works both ways
        jQuery('a[rel*=lightbox]').each(function() {
        //push only unique lightbox[gallery_name] into boxen array
        if (jQuery.inArray(jQuery(this).attr('rel'),boxen)) boxen.push(jQuery(this).attr('rel'));
    });
    //for each unique lightbox group, apply the lightBox
    jQuery(boxen).each(function(i,val) { jQuery('a[rel='+val+']').lightBox(); });
    });
</script>
```

This is an example mixing all possible uses, they all can work in the same html, here we have two galleries and a third one with no name, just the "lightbox" reference:

```
<a href="images/image1.jpg" rel="lightbox[gallery1]"><img border="0" height="50" src="images/image1_thumbnail.jpg" width="50" />
<a href="images/image2.jpg" rel="lightbox[gallery1]"><img border="0" height="50" src="images/image2_thumbnail.jpg" width="50" />
<a href="images/image3.jpg" rel="lightbox[gallery2]"><img border="0" height="50" src="images/image3_thumbnail.jpg" width="50" />
<a href="images/image4.jpg" rel="lightbox[gallery2]"><img border="0" height="50" src="images/image4_thumbnail.jpg" width="50" />
<a href="images/image5.jpg" rel="lightbox"><img border="0" height="50" src="images/image5_thumbnail.jpg" width="50" />
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 4):

I do it this way:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('.lightboxGallery').each(function(){
            $('.lightbox', this).lightBox();
        });
    });
</script>
```

This way all you have to do is place each gallery in some kind of container and you'll get one image set per container, for example, the following will create two image sets:

```
<div id="gallery1" class="lightboxGallery">
    <a href="image1.jpg" class="lightbox">Image 1</a><br />
    <a href="image2.jpg" class="lightbox">Image 2</a><br />
    <a href="image3.jpg" class="lightbox">Image 3</a><br />
</div>
<div id="gallery2" class="lightboxGallery">
  <a href="image4.jpg" class="lightbox">Image 4</a><br />
  <a href="image5.jpg" class="lightbox">Image 5</a><br />
  <a href="image6.jpg" class="lightbox">Image 6</a><br />
</div>
```

You could use the 'a' selector instead but I find using '.lightbox' offers more flexibility.

Comment: This is the best solution by far. Thanks, works great with just using "a" tag instead adding ".lightbox" to every link.

Answer (score 1):

Alternately, you could do something like this to automatically wire up any lightbox[*insert gallery name here*] links, like the standard lightbox.js functionality:

```
$(function() {
  var boxen = [];

  //find all links w/ rel=lightbox[...
  $('a[rel*=lightbox\\[]').each(function() {

    //push only unique lightbox[gallery_name] into boxen array
    if ($.inArray($(this).attr('rel'),boxen)) boxen.push($(this).attr('rel'));

  });

  //for each unique lightbox group, apply the lightBox
  $(boxen).each(function(i,val) { $('a[rel='+val+']').lightBox(); });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

All you need is lightbox 2 which you can get it from the link below.

http://www.huddletogether.com/projects/lightbox2/

```
<a href="images/image-1.jpg" rel="lightbox[roadtrip]">image #1</a>
<a href="images/image-2.jpg" rel="lightbox[roadtrip]">image #2</a>
<a href="images/image-3.jpg" rel="lightbox[roadtrip]">image #3</a>
```

You can set your different sets of gallery using "lightbox[roadtrip]" just rename the "roadtrip" with your desired gallery group name and it'll work like magic. No need to code for anything extra

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps lightbox has changed since other answers were given, but I thought the answers on this page were good, but then I discovered that I could simply do:

```
    jQuery('.lightbox').each(function(){
            jQuery('a', this).lightBox();
    });
```

That assumes an HTML structure of:

```
<div class="lightbox">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <a href="asdasd.jpg"><img src="asdasd.jpg"></a>
    <a href="asdasd2.jpg"><img src="asdasd2.jpg"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

The wrapper class isn't needed, I think, but my code included it for other reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Can't say I've worked with this particular plugin before, but usually you add a `rel=lightbox[foo]` to the link element. Foo will be unique for each gallery on the page.

Hope this gets you started on the right path; otherwise there are [dozens](http://planetozh.com/projects/lightbox-clones/) of other lightbox plugins you can use.

Comment: jQuery lightbox lets you use whatever selector you want to bind light box to an element.  so you don't *have* to put rel="lightbox[optional_slide_show]" on your elements any more (like in the original version).  however, you can mimic this behavior with the `$( '[rel*="lightbox"]' )` jQuery selector.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I made the basic jquery lightbox linked in the original question behave with multiple galleries. No hacks, or anything. Works flawlessly.

I gave every lightbox a seperate name:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$(function() {
    $('a[@rel*=lightboxG1]').lightBox();
    $('a[@rel*=lightboxG2]').lightBox();
});
</script>
```

Then my HTML looks like this:

```
<a href="images/image-1.jpg" rel="lightboxG1">image #1</a>
<a href="images/image-2.jpg" rel="lightboxG1">image #2</a>
<a href="images/image-3.jpg" rel="lightboxG1">image #3</a>

<a href="images/image-1.jpg" rel="lightboxG2">image #1</a>
<a href="images/image-2.jpg" rel="lightboxG2">image #2</a>
<a href="images/image-3.jpg" rel="lightboxG2">image #3</a>
```

And voila, I have 2 separate galleries.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it without JavaScript at all with the data-attributes.

```
<div id="gallery-1">
    <a href="images/image-1.jpg" data-lightbox="gallery-1" data-title="Gallery 1 Image 1"><img src="images/image-1.jpg"></a>
    <a href="images/image-2.jpg" data-lightbox="gallery-1" data-title="Gallery 1 Image 2"><img src="images/image-2.jpg"></a>
    <a href="images/image-3.jpg" data-lightbox="gallery-1" data-title="Gallery 1 Image 3"><img src="images/image-3.jpg"></a>
</div>
<div id="gallery-2">
    <a href="images/image-4.jpg" data-lightbox="gallery-2" data-title="Gallery 2 Image 1"><img src="images/image-4.jpg"></a>
    <a href="images/image-5.jpg" data-lightbox="gallery-2" data-title="Gallery 2 Image 2"><img src="images/image-5.jpg"></a>
    <a href="images/image-6.jpg" data-lightbox="gallery-2" data-title="Gallery 2 Image 3"><img src="images/image-6.jpg"></a>
</div>
<div id="gallery-3">
    <a href="images/image-7.jpg" data-lightbox="gallery-3" data-title="Gallery 3 Image 1"><img src="images/image-7.jpg"></a>
    <a href="images/image-8.jpg" data-lightbox="gallery-3" data-title="Gallery 3 Image 2"><img src="images/image-8.jpg"></a>
    <a href="images/image-9.jpg" data-lightbox="gallery-3" data-title="Gallery 3 Image 3"><img src="images/image-9.jpg"></a>
</div>
<div id="gallery-4">
    <a href="images/image-10.jpg" data-lightbox="gallery-4" data-title="Gallery 4 Image 1"><img src="images/image-10.jpg"></a>
    <a href="images/image-11.jpg" data-lightbox="gallery-4" data-title="Gallery 4 Image 2"><img src="images/image-11.jpg"></a>
    <a href="images/image-12.jpg" data-lightbox="gallery-4" data-title="Gallery 4 Image 3"><img src="images/image-12.jpg"></a>
</div>
```

It works also if the images are mixed up in the page.

```
<div id="gallery">
    <a href="images/image-1.jpg" data-lightbox="gallery-1" data-title="Gallery 1 Image 1"><img src="images/image-1.jpg"></a>
    <a href="images/image-4.jpg" data-lightbox="gallery-2" data-title="Gallery 2 Image 1"><img src="images/image-4.jpg"></a>
    <a href="images/image-2.jpg" data-lightbox="gallery-1" data-title="Gallery 1 Image 2"><img src="images/image-2.jpg"></a>
    <a href="images/image-9.jpg" data-lightbox="gallery-3" data-title="Gallery 3 Image 3"><img src="images/image-9.jpg"></a>
    <a href="images/image-3.jpg" data-lightbox="gallery-1" data-title="Gallery 1 Image 3"><img src="images/image-3.jpg"></a>
    <a href="images/image-8.jpg" data-lightbox="gallery-3" data-title="Gallery 3 Image 2"><img src="images/image-8.jpg"></a>
    <a href="images/image-5.jpg" data-lightbox="gallery-2" data-title="Gallery 2 Image 2"><img src="images/image-5.jpg"></a>
    <a href="images/image-12.jpg" data-lightbox="gallery-4" data-title="Gallery 4 Image 3"><img src="images/image-12.jpg"></a>
    <a href="images/image-10.jpg" data-lightbox="gallery-4" data-title="Gallery 4 Image 1"><img src="images/image-10.jpg"></a>
    <a href="images/image-6.jpg" data-lightbox="gallery-2" data-title="Gallery 2 Image 3"><img src="images/image-6.jpg"></a>
    <a href="images/image-7.jpg" data-lightbox="gallery-3" data-title="Gallery 3 Image 1"><img src="images/image-7.jpg"></a>
    <a href="images/image-11.jpg" data-lightbox="gallery-4" data-title="Gallery 4 Image 2"><img src="images/image-11.jpg"></a>
</div>
```