# How to make multiple jQuery LightBox galleries work on one page

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightbox

I can't seem to get multiple JQuery LightBox galleries to work on on HTML page. I have already tried all the suggestions on a [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051294/making-jquery-lightbox-plugin-work-with-multiple-galleries) someone did a while back but I still can't get it to work!

Here is a bit of background info...

I have developed a static HTML page which contains three separate Lightbox galleries. The first gallery loads and works perfectly, but the second and third galleries fail to load; neither displaying the hyperlinked image (that triggers the lightbox gallery) or the images within that one gallery, I just get the 'loading' animation.

I am calling the Lightbox javascript in the  of the HTML and have duplicated the Javascript calling function for the second and third galleries, calling them "#gallery1 a", "#gallery2 a", "#gallery3 a" etc, but it still doesn't work.

I know the three galleries work together because if I duplicate the first gallery (including all of images that are for gallery 1) and paste it again below, all three galleries work. The problem comes when I change the filename of the photo's that I want in the second and third galleries.

I have attached below an extract from `<head>` the and also the html from the static page so you can see everything I have done so far.

It would be greatly appreciated if someone could please point out where I am going wrong to get all three of these galleries to work.

Many thanks in advance...

Here is the HEAD of the HTML:

```
<head>
$(function() {
    $('#gallery a').lightBox();
});

$(function() {
    $('#gallery1 a').lightBox();
});

$(function() {
    $('#gallery2 a').lightBox();
});

$(function() {
    $('#gallery3 a').lightBox();
});
</head>
```

Now for the HTML:

```
<div id="gallery">
<ul>
<li>
<a href="portfolio/Bathroom install 2 watermarked/ian work photos 089.jpg">
<img src="portfolio/Bathroom install 2 watermarked/ian work photos 112.jpg"/>
</a>
<li><a href="portfolio/Bathroom install 2 watermarked/ian work photos 090.jpg"></a>
</li>
<li><a href="portfolio/Bathroom install 2 watermarked/ian work photos 111.jpg"></a>
</li>
<li><a href="portfolio/Bathroom install 2 watermarked/ian work photos 112.jpg"></a>
</li>
<li><a href="portfolio/Bathroom install 2 watermarked/ian work photos 113.jpg"></a>
</li>
<li><a href="portfolio/Bathroom install 2 watermarked/ian work photos 114.jpg"></a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>

<div id="gallery1">
<ul>
<li>
<a href="portfolio/Bathroom install 3 watermarked/ian work photos 089.jpg">
<img src="portfolio/Bathroom install 3 watermarked/ian work photos 182.jpg"/>
</a>
<li><a href="portfolio/Bathroom install 3 watermarked/ian work photos 183.jpeg"></a>
</li>
<li><a href="portfolio/Bathroom install 3 watermarked/ian work photos 184.jpg"></a>
</li>
<li><a href="portfolio/Bathroom install 3 watermarked/ian work photos 185.jpg"></a>
</li>
<li><a href="portfolio/Bathroom install 3 watermarked/ian work photos 186.jpg"></a>
</li>
<li><a href="portfolio/Bathroom install 3 watermarked/ian work photos 187.jpg"></a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You should use `lightbox gallery` *classes* instead of the multiple IDs select for this type of issue. Note how you've got nearly identical repetition in the jQuery part? Use a class, this is what classes are for, and then `$('.lightbox.gallery a')` (note the two `.`) once would suffice.

Comment: you missed the <script> tag just here? or in the real code too?

Comment: @AtaurRahimChowdhury - The OP indicates in the question that the first works, so I imagine that's just the way they chose to show the code.

Comment: @JaredFarrish yah, me too. just in case.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2197407/451969) from the question you've linked to I would say is what I would suggest you do instead.