# Automatically add rel="lightbox" AND sort some galleries

Tags: jquery, lightbox, blogger

I have a blogger (blogspot) page and am trying to utilise jquery-lightbox 0.5.  I've got it working, but would like to add some functionality.

At the moment I have it so that all the images on one post are shown, though together album-like.

Using this script:

```
$(function() {
$('a[href$=jpg], a[href$=JPG], a[href$=jpeg], a[href$=JPEG], a[href$=png], a[href$=gif], a[href$=bmp]:has(img)').lightBox();
});
```

What I'd prefer is to have the images open as individual images (not grouped together), unless that is I manually add some sort of album id attribute.  What I'm thinking is that if I can automatically add rel="lightbox" to all images found on the page, AND then any images I'd like to collate together into albums would be under a manually added id="albumname".

Any ideas, I can't even get rel="lightbox" appended automatically :(  I'm not great at this, so apologies.

The page so far is at [blog.talesfromthesaddle.com](http://blog.talesfromthesaddle.com) though lightbox is set to only work on individual posts: eg http://blog.talesfromthesaddle.com/2012/12/bolivia-part-one-west.html

I found some reasonable scripts here : [Making JQuery LightBox Plugin work with multiple galleries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051294/making-jquery-lightbox-plugin-work-with-multiple-galleries) but I'm a bit confused....

Thanks for any help you can offer,
Nick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I did in the end:

```
$("a[href$='.jpg'],a[href$='.png'],a[href$='.gif']").attr("rel", "Your_rel_here").fancybox();
```

Thanks to Matias too who pointed me in the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```
$("img").each(function()
{
    $(this).attr("rel", "lightbox");
});
```

And keep in mind that if you want to "group" the images, instead of `id` you should use `class`

**CODE EDIT**: I think this also works

```
$("img").attr("rel", "lightbox");
```

Comment: Thanks for looking Matías, I'm trying this now....also trying fancybox.  I think with lightbox I have to add the rel information to the <a> tag....anyway, let me have a look!  Thanks!!