# JQuery LightBox plugin not working with multiple galleries with images as the gallery links

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, lightbox

I am trying to get the LightBox JQuery plugin to work with multiple galleries on the same HTML page. I have tried the solutions for this issue from this post:

[Making JQuery LightBox Plugin work with multiple galleries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051294/making-jquery-lightbox-plugin-work-with-multiple-galleries)

but have not been able to get it to work.

My script looks like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('.lightboxGallery').each(function(){
        $('.lightbox', this).lightbox();
    });
});
</script>
```

And my HTML looks like:

```
<div id="gallery1" class="lightboxGallery">
    <a href="images/gallery/image1.jpg" class="lightbox"><img style="border:3px solid silver;" src="images/image10.jpg"></a>
    <a href="images/gallery/image2.jpg" class="lightbox"></a>
    <a href="images/gallery/image3.jpg" class="lightbox"></a>
    <a href="images/gallery/image4.jpg" class="lightbox"></a>
</div>
<div id="gallery2" class="lightboxGallery">
    <a href="images/gallery/image5.jpg" class="lightbox"><img style="border:3px solid silver;" src="images/pic10.jpg"></a>
    <a href="images/gallery/image6.jpg" class="lightbox"></a>
    <a href="images/gallery/image7.jpg" class="lightbox"></a>
    <a href="images/gallery/image8.jpg" class="lightbox"></a>
    <a href="images/gallery/image9.jpg" class="lightbox"></a>
</div>
```

When this is run, if I click on the first image to display what is supposed to be the first gallery, it shows image10.jpg and then the images in gallery2: image5, image6, image7, image8, image9. If I were to add another div for gallery 3:

```
<div id="gallery3" class="lightboxGallery">
    <a href="images/gallery/image11.jpg" class="lightbox"><img style="border:3px solid silver;" src="images/pic11.jpg"></a>
    <a href="images/gallery/image12.jpg" class="lightbox"></a>
    <a href="images/gallery/image13.jpg" class="lightbox"></a>
    <a href="images/gallery/image14.jpg" class="lightbox"></a>
    <a href="images/gallery/image15.jpg" class="lightbox"></a>
</div>
```

And I clicked on the image that is supposed to show images from gallery 1, it would show image10.jpg and then the images in gallery3: image11, image12, image13, image14, image15.

It is like when another lightbox gets created by the script, the ones before it are overwritten or deleted? Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to define multiple scripts named separately inside script tag for each of your gallery . With same name can't be used in multiple galleries